# Read Usb Data Without Blocking UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This function gets usb data from usb device if any new data occurs:

**gpiointerface.java**

```
  //usb input data handler
  private class handler_thread  extends Thread {
        FileInputStream instream;

        handler_thread(FileInputStream stream ){
            instream = stream;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while(READ_ENABLE)
            {
                try{
                    if(instream != null)
                    {
                    readcount = instream.read(usbdata,0,4);
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }
   }
```

I can reach `usbdata` with this function:

```
 /*read port*/
 public byte ReadPort(){
        return usbdata[1];
 }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

If any new data read by `handler_thread` I want to send that new data to MainActivity immediately and show in UI.

I come up with this AsyncTask but It doesn't show new data in UI after new data occurs.

**MainActivity.java**

```
class usbrun extends AsyncTask<Byte, String, Byte>
{
    @Override
    protected Byte doInBackground(Byte... params) {
        try {
            inData = gpiointerface.ReadPort();   //Get usbdata
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inData;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Byte result) {
        readdata.setText(Integer.toHexString(result));  //Show in UI
        Log.d("LED", "istegeldi "+ result);

    }
}
```

---

*Full Code*

**gpiointerface.java**

```
//User must modify the below package with their package name
/******************************FT311 GPIO interface class******************************************/
public class FT311GPIOInterface extends Activity
{

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =    "com.GPIODemo.USB_PERMISSION";
    public UsbManager usbmanager;
    public UsbAccessory usbaccessory;
    public PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    public ParcelFileDescriptor filedescriptor;
    public FileInputStream inputstream;
    public FileOutputStream outputstream;
    public boolean mPermissionRequestPending = false;
    public boolean READ_ENABLE = true;
    public handler_thread handlerThread;

    private byte [] usbdata; 
    private byte [] writeusbdata;
    private int readcount;

    public byte inData;

    public Context global_context;

    public static String ManufacturerString = "mManufacturer=FTDI";
    public static String ModelString = "mModel=FTDIGPIODemo";
    public static String VersionString = "mVersion=1.0";

        /*constructor*/
     public FT311GPIOInterface(Context context){
            super();
            global_context = context;
            /*shall we start a thread here or what*/
            usbdata = new byte[4]; 
            writeusbdata = new byte[4];

            /***********************USB handling******************************************/

            usbmanager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            //Log.d("LED", "usbmanager" +usbmanager);
            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
            context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

            inputstream = null;
            outputstream = null;
        }

/*  reset port*/
     public void ResetPort()
     {
        writeusbdata[0] = 0x14;
        writeusbdata[1] = 0x00;
        writeusbdata[2] = 0x00;
        writeusbdata[3] = 0x00;

         new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                 new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         try {
                             if(outputstream != null){
                                 outputstream.write(writeusbdata,0,4);
                             }
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 30);
     }


        /*read port*/
        public byte ReadPort(){
            Log.d("LED", "istegeldi "+ Integer.toHexString(usbdata[1] & 0xff));
            return usbdata[1];
        }

        /*resume accessory*/
        public void ResumeAccessory()
        {
            // Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (inputstream != null && outputstream != null) {
                return;
            }

            UsbAccessory[] accessories = usbmanager.getAccessoryList();
            if(accessories != null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(global_context, "Accessory Attached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            UsbAccessory accessory = (accessories == null ? null : accessories[0]);
            if (accessory != null) {
                if( -1 == accessory.toString().indexOf(ManufacturerString))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(global_context, "Manufacturer is not matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if( -1 == accessory.toString().indexOf(ModelString))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(global_context, "Model is not matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if( -1 == accessory.toString().indexOf(VersionString))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(global_context, "Version is not matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Toast.makeText(global_context, "Manufacturer, Model & Version are matched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (usbmanager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
                    OpenAccessory(accessory);
                } 
                else
                {
                    synchronized (mUsbReceiver) {
                        if (!mPermissionRequestPending) {
                            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Request USB Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            usbmanager.requestPermission(accessory,
                                    mPermissionIntent);
                            mPermissionRequestPending = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {}

        }

        /*destroy accessory*/
        public void DestroyAccessory(){

            READ_ENABLE = false;  // set false condition for handler_thread to exit waiting data loop
//          ResetPort(); // send dummy data for instream.read going
            try{Thread.sleep(10);}
            catch(Exception e){}
            CloseAccessory();
        }

/*********************helper routines*************************************************/     

        public void OpenAccessory(UsbAccessory accessory)
        {
            filedescriptor = usbmanager.openAccessory(accessory);
            if(filedescriptor != null){
                usbaccessory = accessory;
                FileDescriptor fd = filedescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                inputstream = new FileInputStream(fd);
                outputstream = new FileOutputStream(fd);
                /*check if any of them are null*/
                if(inputstream == null || outputstream==null){
                    return;
                }
            }

            handlerThread = new handler_thread(inputstream);
            handlerThread.start();
        }

        private void CloseAccessory()
        {
            try{
                if(filedescriptor != null)
                    filedescriptor.close();

            }catch (IOException e){}

            try {
                if(inputstream != null)
                        inputstream.close();
            } catch(IOException e){}

            try {
                if(outputstream != null)
                        outputstream.close();

            }catch(IOException e){}
            /*FIXME, add the notfication also to close the application*/

            filedescriptor = null;
            inputstream = null;
            outputstream = null;

            System.exit(0);
        }


        /***********USB broadcast receiver*******************************************/
        private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) 
                {
                    synchronized (this)
                    {
                        UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Allow USB Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            OpenAccessory(accessory);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Deny USB Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("LED", "permission denied for accessory "+ accessory);
                        }
                        mPermissionRequestPending = false;
                    }
                } 
                else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) 
                {
                        CloseAccessory();
                }else
                {
                    Log.d("LED", "....");
                }
            }   
        };

        //usb input data handler
        private class handler_thread  extends Thread {
            FileInputStream instream;

            handler_thread(FileInputStream stream ){
                instream = stream;
            }

            public void run()
            {
                while(READ_ENABLE)
                {
                    try{
                        if(instream != null)
                        {
                        readcount = instream.read(usbdata,0,4);

                        }
                    }catch (IOException e){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
/*FT311 GPIO interface exposes the following methods:
 *   ConfigPort, WritePort and ReadPort are for user to use for port operations.
 *   - ConfigPort(outMap, inMap): to configure the port as input or output, with outMap and inMap 
 *                                are arguments for out bitmap and input bitmap.
 *   - WritePort(outData): to write the port data, with outData as argument.
 *   - ReadPort: to read port, it returns the current level on the input IOs.
 *   
 *   DestroyAccessory and ResumeAccessory methods should be called from
 *   overridden  from onResume() and onDestroy routines of main activity class.
 *   
 *   - DestoryAccessory: to be called from onDestory routine of main activity class.
 *   - ResumeAccessory: to be called from onResume routine of main activity class.
 *   
 *   
 */

public class GPIODemoActivity extends Activity {

    /*declare a FT311 GPIO interface variable*/
    public FT311GPIOInterface gpiointerface;

    /*button object*/
    public Button readbutton;

    /*text boxes for data display*/
    public EditText readdata;

    /*variables*/
    public byte inData; /*input Data*/

    public String sstt;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*text boxes for data display*/
        readdata = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.readdata);

        /**** command buttons*****/
        readbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readbutton);

/******************************process button presses*********************************/


        /*user code to read the accessory data*/
        readbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //readbutton.setBackgroundResource(drawable.start);
                inData = gpiointerface.ReadPort();

                readdata.setText(Integer.toHexString(inData & 0xff));
                //ProcessReadData(inData);
            }
        });

        /*create an object of GPIO interface class*/
         gpiointerface = new FT311GPIOInterface(this);
         resetFT311();

         new usbrun().execute();

    }


    class usbrun extends AsyncTask<Byte, String, Byte>
    {
        @Override
        protected Byte doInBackground(Byte... params) {
            try {
                inData = gpiointerface.ReadPort();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return inData;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Byte result) {
            readdata.setText("asd");
        }
    }



    protected void resetFT311(){
        gpiointerface.ResetPort();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Ideally should implement onResume() and onPause()
        // to take appropriate action when the activity looses focus
        super.onResume();
        gpiointerface.ResumeAccessory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Ideally should implement onResume() and onPause()
        // to take appropriate action when the activity looses focus
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy(){

        gpiointerface.DestroyAccessory();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you specify what "doesn't seem to work" means in the context of your `AsyncTask` please? Maybe it helps clarify your problem

Comment: I edit the question and made more clear I hope. I wanted to see `usbdata` in UI immediately after new data occurs.

Comment: I see. But does logcat show that onPostExecute() is called?

Comment: Only in beginning of the program once

Comment: okay, based on your feedback: in onPostExcute(..) test if your View displays correctly by calling readdata.setText("just to see if it renders");

Comment: If yes, the problem lies in the way you handle the asynctask. If no, the problem is with your view.

Comment: Post the full Code for the problem then :D and we will find the error

Comment: My view displays correctly the string. As you said, problem lies in AsyncTask probably. I posted :)

Comment: The code for the MainActivity you posted, shows no reason this shouldn't work.
Basically, the AsyncTask is executed, the result arrives on the UIThread and the View shows "asd".
So the problem should be the result you're reading here `gpiointerface.ReadPort();`

Comment: For the `AsyncTask` only executing once, that is the designed behaviour.
Each time the `Activity` is (re-)created, the task is newly created and fired once.

Comment: AsyncTask not fit for my needs then. Can I push new data from `handler_thread ` to MainActivity if new data occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Abstract background thread class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPollThread extends Thread {

//the default amount of bytes to read at once
public static final int DEFAULT_PACKET_SIZE = 4;

//flag indicating wether this thread should still run
private volatile boolean isFinished = false;

//the input stream to obtain bytes from
private InputStream inputStream;

//the packet size specified in constructor
private int packetSize;

//constructor using packetSize = DEFAULT_PACKET_SIZE
public AbstractPollThread(@NonNull InputStream inputStream) {
    this(inputStream, DEFAULT_PACKET_SIZE);
}

//constructor using custom packetSize
public AbstractPollThread(@NonNull InputStream inputStream, int packetSize) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
    this.packetSize = packetSize;
}

//notify this Thread that it should finish
public void finish() {
    isFinished = true;
    interrupt();
}

//this thread's loop method
@Override
public void run() {
    //loop while finish() has not been called
    while (!isFinished) {
        try {
            //obtain the next packetSize bytes as array
            //this blocks until at least packetSize bytes are available
            byte[] packet = nextPacket();

            //invoke abstract handle method and pass the packet we just read
            handlePacket(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        //try to close the underlying stream
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Child classes need to implement this method
protected abstract void handlePacket(byte[] packet);

private byte[] nextPacket() throws IOException {
    //create a new byte array of packetSize length
    byte[] bytePacket = new byte[packetSize];

    //read in a loop, until exactly packetSize bytes are read
    int c = 0;
    while (c < packetSize) {
        int r = inputStream.read(bytePacket, c, packetSize - c);
        if (r == -1) {
            //if this stream is closed, call finish() on this Thread
            finish();
        } else {
            //increment the index by the amount of bytes we could read at once
            c += r;
        }
    }

    //return the bytePacket we just read
    return bytePacket;
}
}
```

actual background thread implementation:

```
public class BufferedPollThread extends AbstractPollThread {

//the initial capacity of the packet buffer
public static final int INITIAL_BUFFER_CAPACITY = 16;

//the read handler that wants to receive packets
private ReadHandler readHandler;

//handler hooked to the UIThread's message loop
private Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

//a simple list implementation acting as packetBuffer
private List<byte[]> packetBuffer = new ArrayList<>(INITIAL_BUFFER_CAPACITY);

//same constructor as in AbstractPollThread
public BufferedPollThread(@NonNull InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
}

//same constructor as in AbstractPollThread
public BufferedPollThread(@NonNull InputStream inputStream, int packetSize) {
    super(inputStream, packetSize);
}

public void setReadHandler(ReadHandler readHandler) {
    //set the Handler that should handle packets
    this.readHandler = readHandler;

    //if the buffer contains packets, push them to the readHandler
        if (packetBuffer.size() > 0) {
            for (byte[] packet : packetBuffer)
                handlePacket(packet);
        }
        packetBuffer.clear();
}

public void clearReadHandler() {
    //clear the reference to the Handler to avoid memory leaks
    this.readHandler = null;
}

@Override
protected void handlePacket(final byte[] packet) {
    //if a handler is set, push the packet directly
    //otherwise add it to buffer
        uiThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (readHandler != null)
                    readHandler.onReadPacket(packet);
                else
                    packetBuffer.add(packet);
            }
        });
}

public interface ReadHandler {
    //this is called for every packet in your custom read handler
    void onReadPacket(byte[] packet);
}
}
```

an example setup for your main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BufferedPollThread.ReadHandler {

//hold the reference to the pollThread
private BufferedPollThread bufferedPollThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //do your setup here (FileInputStream implements InputStream, so no problems here)
    InputStream usbInputStream = null; //Open the FileInputStream to USB here

    //create and start the pollThread that will deliver USB read packets
    bufferedPollThread = new BufferedPollThread(usbInputStream);
    bufferedPollThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //if this activity is about to be destroyed, stop the background poll thread as well
    bufferedPollThread.finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //if this activity is in foreground, listen to packets from USB
    bufferedPollThread.setReadHandler(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    //if this activity is about to be paused, stop listening to packets from USB
    //this is to avoid memory leaks on configuration changes
    bufferedPollThread.clearReadHandler();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onReadPacket(byte[] packet) {
    //This method is called on the UIThread, so you can do all your View updates here
}
}
```

see https://github.com/newcrows/UsbExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/crowsnet/usbexample for source

Comment: Thank you for your time. I couldn't make it work. I have searched the google for solution but I couldn't find any. Problems: `private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` Cannot resolve symbol 'Looper',  `mHandler.post(Runnable task);` Cannot resolve symbol 'mHandler' and 'task'

Comment: i edited the answer, i am sorry, i thought you would just use auto-import of android studio. my bad

Comment: I was using but It didn't import. Since `handler_thread` is in `gpiointerface.java`, can I access `mHandler` and `readdata` from there? Because both are defined in `MainActivity`

Comment: If you just copy paste the 3 classes behind the link, usb background reading with progress notification in the UIThread is taken care of

Comment: I'm really appreciate your effort. I have problem with your last update: `error: package android.support.annotation does not exist` It tried to add support.annotation in SDK manager and dependencies but nothing changed. I don't think @NonNull should be delete but anyway I tried to delete @NonNull but then application stop at the launch.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and i will have a look. I can just drag and drop the project from github and it works flawlessly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169623/discussion-between-ilvthsgm-and-jan-mund).